# Issue with highlighting page elements using mouseover and mouseout event listeners

Tags: javascript, onclick, firefox-addon, highlight, onmouseover

I am creating a Firefox extension that gets some information about an element on a webpage (say, the element's `id` attribute), upon clicking said element. I also would like to implement a feature in which hovering over the element will highlight it.

There are some existing solutions that essentially already do this. It seems that these existing solutions (such the "Select element with mouse" feature in Firefox's "Inspector" tool) essentially make use of two event listeners:

- A `mouseover` listener: Highlights whatever element you move your mouse over an element.
- A `mouseout` listener: Removes the highlighting when you move your mouse off of an element. (Otherwise, as you move your mouse over the whole page, eventually everything will be highlighted!)

I have attempted to make my own implementation which uses those two listeners (`onmouseover` and `onmouseout`). The highlighting is applied in the same manner as the linktargetfinder in [this tutorial](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/): whenever we want an element to be highlighted, we add a `link-target-finder-selected` property to the element's `class` attribute. A `link` reference to the CSS file is put into the `head` of the HTML document and refers to this CSS code:

```
.link-target-finder-selected {
    outline: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

This implementation is very close to what we want, but unfortunately, there are a few (most likely related) issues.

First, with text boxes, the highlighting only applies when the mouse is on the border of the text box. Once you move into the interior of the text box, apparently the `mouseout` event is triggered -- the highlighting disappears, even though it is clear to you or me that the mouse is actually still hovering over the text box. It seems that I need to somehow force the `mouseout` event to *not* trigger until you move the mouse *completely* outside of the text box.

Second, I am having a very similar issue with multiple-select boxes. But I also want the behavior for multiple-select boxes to be somewhat nonstandard. The actual behavior is that a mouse-over will highlight the select box; the highlight will disappear as you begin to move inside the select box, and then the options within the select box will get highlighted as you move over them. Instead, I would like my add-on to function such that, upon entering the select box, the box will be highlighted, and nothing else will be highlighted or highlighted until the mouse leaves the entire box. The solution to this should essentially be the same as the solution to the text box issue.

Please let me know if you have any ideas for how I can fix these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave a solution to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21598914/1828637

I do the same thing in my addon which i hope to release soon.

the mouseout event should not trigger when you move into the middle of a input field, thats weird.

if that really happens then on mouseover the input field, then add a MouseLeave event, (opposite of moustEnter event)

so still to the body add the event listener for mouseoever, and when an element is mousedover then it should un-outline the previously selected element (this is for robustness) and should add a mouseLeave event that will un-outline itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about mouseleave! I was only aware of mouseover and mouseout. I didn't use a mouseenter listener, though. Instead, in my mouseover event, I check if the element is a text box; if so, I disable the mouseover and mouseout listeners and add a mouseleave listener to that element. Then, the mouseleave listener does the opposite: it removes itself, and re-enables the mouseover and mouseout listeners. Now text boxes highlights properly. Also, I wasn't aware you could use `.style.outline` to set the outline directly; that helped, too. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, I like setting outline more then border as outline doesn't affect the objects around it, like it doesnt change the offsetTop offsetLeft or offsetHeight or offsetWidth I guess, if i do border things around it move.

Comment: also are you sure about doing that for textboxes? i just test my code i posted on the topic over there, i dont have to do that trick for textboxes. ill post the code again below

Answer (score 0):

try this code, when i tried it i didnt have to do the trick you did for textboxes:

```
var lastBoxedEl;

function moused(e) {
    var target = e.target; //experiment, try e.currentTarget, e.originanalTarget
    if (lastBoxedEl) {
        lastBoxedEl.style.outline = 'none'
    }
    lastBoxedEl = target;
    target.style.outline = '5px solid red';
}
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', moused, false);
```

you are using this in html right? i dont know how this would behave in xul

Comment: The code I'm using is essentially the same, and that "trick" is necessary for text boxes, on my computer. I'm using Firefox 24.0 (yes, out of date, but for a reason...) on Windows 7 Enterprise.

What are you using to remove the highlighting? Is it a `mouseout` event listener? That's what I use; I don't think you would want to use a `mouseleave` listener for **all** element highlighting, because you would frequently end up with multiple elements being highlighted at once.

Comment: in that code above, if you copy paste it in scratchpad, give it a try. onmouseover of an element, it un-outlines the last selected element then outlines the new one. i do that by using global var lastBoxedEl. i figure you dont want this mouseoever attached all the time, so when you remoeve that mouseever event listener, just un-outline the last outlined element. its so interesting that this happens in ff24, ill have to give it a test some time, its peculiar it shouldnt be the case

Comment: I see; I was using a `mouseover` event to un-highlight the previously-highlighted element. It appears that this is the cause of the issues. When I use your code (which does everything inside of a `mouseover` event), there is no issue. But having a separate `mouseover` event for highlighting and a `mouseout` event for un-highlighting causes various issues, including the text box issue I mentioned earlier. I will attempt to incorporate this "all-in-one" approach; it seems simpler and is somehow more robust.